# Confuse on dealing with relations between objects using Android Room

Tags: android, persistent-storage, android-room, android-architecture-components, android-architecture

When using the android data-persistent library **Android Room** ,how can I directly insert the `Comment` Object into the database including all the field value, and how can I query all the value out as a Comment Object?

As I know, I can not use the `Comment` Object as a `Entity` in Room directory, because of the field `replyComment` is also a `Comment` Object. And I can not query out a `Comment` Object even I define a POJO using the `@Relations` annotation either because of the one-to-one relations and one-to-many relations all included in the `Comment` Object.

Is there any other way except changing the `Comment` Model definition, such as using foreign key, making a effect on insert action and query action?

```
public class Comment { 
    public String content;
    public String id;
    public Comment replyComment;
    public User user;
    public List<ImageMedia> images;
}

public class User{
    public String id;
    public String name;
}

public class ImageMedia{
    public String key;
    public String url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any other way except changing the Comment Model definition

No. You would need to create a set of entities that model the database structure, where children have foreign key columns pointing back to their parents:

- `CommentEntity` has a foreign key back to `CommentEntity` for the reply
- `CommentEntity` has a foreign key back to `UserEntity`
- `ImageMediaEntity` has a foreign key back to `CommentEntity`

Comment: Actually ,even though I had create a new entity model like you said ,the **Room** has no idea on  helping me insert and query data well.As I know ,I should create a abstract layer to deal with the transform action between the objects and I should do serval insert action to insert all the entity value into their tables ,and do serval query action to query all the entity values out,then make them all in the Comment model that I want.

Comment: @LemonYang: "the Room has no idea on helping me insert and query data well" -- I do not know what you mean by that. Your `@Dao` methods will be on a per-entity basis, with `@Transaction` methods to combine multiple operations. Room provides a thin object layer over SQLite, just as Retrofit provides a thin object layer over REST, Apollo-Android provides a thin object layer over GraphQL, etc.